# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Session: do I need to sweep the data table periodically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, cookies, memcached, session-cookies

We're running a big site and have Rails' default CookieStore in place now.  We want to switch either to memcached or ActiveRecord stores for several reasons.  I am trying to decide which is better.

In the bad old days, I recall we had to run "sweepers" from time to time to clear out expired sessions.  I cannot find any reference to this in the docs and am optimistically thinking "it's magic!!" and Rails 3 removes expired sessions for us.  Do we need to write a periodic task to clear expired sessions from the database?

I know it's bad form to ask two questions in one SO, but given that we have memcached running, I can't see any reason not to use it, instead (and it does automagically expire stuff).  Any reason we shouldn't go straight to memcached for sessions?

Comment: One thing to consider with memcached is that if for whatever reason you need to restart memcached no-ones sessions will persist after the reboot.